# Simulate packet send and recv

Tags: c++, sockets, hook, simulate

I have hooked the send and recv functions for a game process. Now I can handle what is sent and what in received.

My functions are:

```
int __stdcall nSend(SOCKET s, char *buf, int len,int flags)
{
    UnHookFunction("ws2_32.dll", "send", KSendHook);   
    int result = send(s, buf, len, flags); // Send data 
    HookFunction("ws2_32.dll", "send", (LPVOID*) nSend, KSendHook);

    return result; 
}

int __stdcall nRecv(SOCKET s, char *buf, int len, int flags)
{
    UnHookFunction("ws2_32.dll", "recv", KRecvHook); 
    int result = recv(s, buf, len, flags); // Receive data
    HookFunction("ws2_32.dll", "recv", (LPVOID*) nRecv, KRecvHook);

    return result;
}
```

My question is:

I hooked the function so I can only interpret and modify what is sent and received.
I need to send new packets structures as I if I was the game. Using the same socket.

How could I simulate the send and recv for the same socket of hooked functions?

Comment: I tried to use s as a handle, to call send() again with that socket handle. But didnt work.

Comment: In what way did it not work?

Comment: The process crashs. 

I called send just the same way its called at hook.

`send(s, buf, len, flags);`

I saved s and flags in global variables from the hooked send, and then tried to send using the same flags and s. But process crashs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your hooked receive function is called, call the real send and receive functions as needed. When you have data to return to the caller, return it to the caller. When send is called, take the data sent, decide whether you want to send anything to the server or not, and call send and receive to talk to the server as you like.

Comment: I want to call send and recv OUT of the hooking function.

Comment: @ThiagoMarquezini Right, and you should. In the hooking functions, you can `send` to, and `recv` from, the server as you need.

Comment: The ugly bit about hooking is there are a variety of complex functions you need to hook, like [WSASend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Using a filter may be a lot smarter than hooking.

Comment: What you mean with "filter"? I have WSAStartup, socket, connect, accept, send and recv coded. But I only enabled send and recv.

Comment: I saved socket handle 's' to a global variable when I detected the packet 0x02000 sent to server.

Then in another function I tried::

`byte byteArray[6] = {0x06, 0x00, 0x5E, 0x39, 0x00, 0x61};
         
            send(sid, (char*)&byteArray, sizeof(byteArray), 0);`

`sid` is the global 's'

Comment: @ThiagoMarquezini Is that a question?

Comment: @ThiagoMarquezini It's a bit scary because the application may be sending something else at the same time you're trying to send that. But it seems basically okay.

Comment: Hmm ok. Thanks. I will try again later ans then I post updates